# execute find command with xargs in bash script

Tags: bash, find, exec

I'm trying to execute this command in in a bash script

```
find /var/log/apache2/access*.gz -type f -newer ./tmpoldfile ! -newer ./tmpnewfile | xargs zcat | grep -E '$MONTH\/$YEAR.*GET.*ad=$ADVERTISER HTTP\/1' -c
```

If i execute it directly or assign it to a variable it returns 0

But if i do a echo of the command (with the variables replaced by the script) and execute it in the command line it works.

```
echo "find /var/log/apache2/access*.gz -type f -newer ./tmpoldfile ! -newer ./tmpnewfile | xargs zcat | grep -E '$MONTH\/$YEAR.*GET.*ad=$ADVERTISER HTTP\/1' -c"
```

How shold i code it for work

Comment: You don't need xargs at all. Check out the `-exec` argument for `find`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables aren't expanded inside of single quotes, i.e. '...$NOT_EXPANDED ...'. Try

```
find /var/log/apache2/access*.gz -type f -newer ./tmpoldfile ! -newer ./tmpnewfile \
| xargs zcat | grep -E "$MONTH\/$YEAR.*GET.*ad=$ADVERTISER HTTP\/1" -c
# newstuff ------------^------------------------------------------^-----------
```

Same for "or assign it to a variable "

```
varCount=$(find /var/log/apache2/access*.gz -type f -newer ./tmpoldfile ! -newer ./tmpnewfile \
| xargs zcat | grep -E "$MONTH\/$YEAR.*GET.*ad=$ADVERTISER HTTP\/1" -c )
```

Also, I must comment on `-exec`. Many finds now support `find ... -exec ... \+` which is (I assume) the equivalent of `xargs`, but not all OS's have GNU find as their first tool. If you're sure you'll never work in a Solaris, AIX, or HPUX shop, then use the improved features. Also, if you're using new OS's, then `xargs` likely supports parallel processing, which I don't think `find ... -exec ... \+`  will do.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Great! Thats was the problem.